# How to check if a user is online in laravel vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to check if a user is online so I can show a green circle
this is my template

```
<template>
<div>
    <span class="fas fa-circle pull-right text-success" v-if="checkUser"></span>
    <span class="fas fa-circle pull-right text-danger" v-else></span>
</div>
</template>
```

this is my script with props

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "OnlineUser",
    props: ['contact', 'onlineusers'],
    data(){
      return{
      }
    },
    methods:{

    },
    computed:{
        checkUser() {
            return  _.find(this.onlineusers, {id: this.contact});

        },
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    created() {

    }
}
</script>
```

when I check the vue dev tool, all the online users show in there but I tried saving the result of my function to see what it returns and it always return **undefined** intead of **true** or **false**

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most easy way is to define it like this:

````
 ```<script>
        window.loggedIn = {!! json_encode([
        'signedIn'=>Auth::check(),
    ]) !!};
    <script/>```
````

That way you will have a global variable named "loggedIn" that will give you true or false if the user is online or not.

Comment: am using laravel echo to get the online users whenever a user logs in, I don't know how this will work with your code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using lodash to check if the user exists in the onlineusers array.

This is not an error, this is expected behavior, just like the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find) say for the `_.find()` method:

> Returns the matched element, else undefined.

I would recommend using the `_.some()` method:

```
checkUser() {
    return  _.some(this.onlineusers, ['id', this.contact.id});
}
```

Just like the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#some) say:

> Returns true if any element passes the predicate check, else false.

Comment: this is able to return the true or false but my template is still not being rendered according to the condition. I still get **red** circle for all users but the computed value of **checkUser** return true for some of the users

Comment: It looks like this should work, Are you sure those classes are giving you the right colors? Is it rendering the v-if correctly?

Comment: they are basic bootstrap classes, and besides since some of the users are returning true I should see two different colours but its only red that appears indicating that all of them are returning false

Comment: I think the problem is from the **v-if**, I don't really know why but it sometimes work fine the later goes off.